# Hoover upright vacuum, model UH70605. Brush roller does NOT shut off

Tags: vacuum

When either the handle is in the upright position or the manual on/off roller switch for hardwood floors is used, the roller brush continues to rotate.  The roller speed slows, or weakens, but does not stop.  It seems to be running at about 25 to 30% power.  After a few minutes of using the attachment hose with the handle upright, a smell like something getting too warm starts to become apparent.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "small appliance repair" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about small appliance repair.

Comment: do you realize that you described your observation, but you did not ask a question?